# Empathy cannot connect with Google Talk and Facebook

Tags: empathy, connection, facebook, google-talk

My Empathy doesn't connect with Google Talk and Facebook. It worked for the first two weeks (after installation). I am using Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin).

Comment: Also, another similar empathy google-talk question. Please consider reading. I haven`t got a solution yet. [link here!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/135226/empathy-google-talk-with-non-google-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost sounds link mine. Already file a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/997017) since no XMPP services 
work after my upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, its good to see that it is going somewhere. I should have solved a bug report myself. Sorry for wasting your time here.

Answer (score 1):

With the facebook part, make sure you use the user name you have with facebook. This isn't your email. It's a facebook email. But you don't include @facebook.com 
To set one up if you haven't already. Go to account settings on facebook, and then there should be a spot to create a username.

`(it will be at the end of http://www.facebook.com/userNameWouldBeHere`)

Try using that, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Olá amigos.
Dedico esta resposta para amigos Brasileiros que assim como eu, apanhamos muito para logar no facebook pelo Emphaty.
Li este post em Inglês e consegui logar.
O procedimento e muito simples.
Segue a baixo o passo a passo:

1. 1 -> Com o navegador vai até facebook.com 
   2 -> Vá em configurações de conta. 
   3 -> Em configurações de conta você encontrara na segunda
   aba, o tópico nome de usurário. 4 -> Apos ter visto qual seu nome de
   usuário volte ao Emphaty. 5 -> Quando for definir o nome de usuário
   você colocara apenas o nome de usuário, nada mas. 6 -> Depois
   coloque a senha padrão do facebook e pronto.

**From Google translate**

Hello friends. I dedicate this post to friends that Brazilians like me, catch plenty to log into facebook at Emphaty. I read this post in English and got login. The procedure is very simple.

Follow the step by step below:

1.With the browser goes to facebook.com

2.Go to account settings.

3.In account settings you will find in the second tab, the topic name of usury.

4.After seeing what your username return to Emphaty.

5.When you set the username you just put the username, but nothing.

6.Then put the default password of facebook and go.